# How do you count the number of conjugates of a subgroup $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why does the number of conjugates of a subgroup $H$ equal $\lvert [G:N(H)]\rvert$?

I tried looking into this and it seems like manipulation of the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem. I believe it comes down to the Normalizer representing the stabilizer.

If anyone could give a solid explanation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Mark yes, it is the normalizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome new contributor!

Let $X$ be the set of subgroups of $G$ and make $G$ act (on the left) on $X$ by $g.K=gKg^{-1}$ for $g\in G$ and $K\in X$.

Now, if $H\in X$ is a subgroup of $G$, the orbit $\omega$ of $H$ under the action of $G$ on $X$ is equal to the set of conjugates of $H$ in $G$. The Orbit-Stabilizer theorem tells you that $|\omega|=|G|/|S|$ where $S$ denotes the stabilizer of $H$ under the action of $G$. Now, note that $$S=\left\lbrace g\in G: gHg^{-1}=H\right\rbrace$$ which is by definition the normalizer of $H$ in $G$, which you denote by $N(H)$. Thus, you get that the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is $|\omega|=|G|/|S|=|G|/|N(H)|=(G:N(H))$.

Comment: Greetings @Gaussian! Thank you for the response! This clears things up.